# Button Tap Action in UICollectionViewCell in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have this hierarchy.

> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView  -> UICollectionViewCell -> UIButton. 
>   How to i handle tap events on the uibutton using swift4?

Comment: Where do you want to handle the action of button? in ViewController or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `cellForRowAt` do

```
let cell = ///
cell.collectionView.delegate = self
cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

after that you' be able to implement `cellForItemAt` inside the vc , then do

```
let collecCell = ///
collecCell.button.addTarget//////
```

---

```
@objc func buttonClicked(_ bt:UIButton) {}
```

regarding to know which item you can use the `tag` property for that

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In `tableView` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.yourCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
```

In `CollectionView` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.yourBtn.tag = collectionView.tag * 2000 + indexPath.item
```

In Button Action please write :

```
let collectionViewTag = sender.tag / 2000
let index = sender.tag % 2000
```

It may helps you. Thank you.